# Prove that $C^1([a,b];X)$ is a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space with norm $\|\cdot\|$. I want to show that $C^1([a,b];X)$ (the space of continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$ with values in $X$) provided with the norm $$\|u\|_{C^1([a,b];X)}:=\max_{t\in[a,b]}(\|u(t)\|+\|u'(t)\|)$$
is a Banach space.

I think I need to show that any given Cauchy sequence converges in $C^1([a,b];X)$. But how do I begin? I havent got too comfortable with Banach spaces yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Consider a Cauchy sequence $f_n$ in $C^1([a,b];X)$. Show that both $f_n$ and their derivatives $f_n'$ converge in $C^0([a,b]; X)$ with the uniform norm. Suppose $f_n\to f$ and $f_n'\to g$ in $C^0([a,b];X)$. Now prove that $f'=g$, which is a well-known conclusion in real-analysis, hence $f_n\to f$ in $C^1([a,b];X)$.

Comment: It is easier to prove that $\int g = f$.

Comment: Thank you, seems plausible to me. Will try to continue..

Comment: Is it right that since $X$ is complete our sequence $(f_n)$ converges to a continous function $f \in X$...

Comment: @UserUser Yes. The proof is just the same as the elementary statement "if continuous functions $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, then $f$ is continuous".

Comment: Does one need to make use of the given norm?

Comment: @CaveJohnson Can you please have a look at my solution that I posted below? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So let $(f_n)$ be an arbitrary Cauchy sequence in $C^1([a,b]:X)$. Since $X$ is complete $(f_n)$ converges in $C^0([a,b]);X)$ with the uniform norm to $f$.
Similarly, $(f'_n)$ converges in $C^0([a,b]);X)$ with the uniform to a function $g$.
We observe that $$\int g =\int \lim f'_n=\lim \int f'_n=\lim f_n =f$$

Hence, $g=f'$ and we can conclude that $f'\in C^0([a,b];X)$.

Is my proof right? If so, where do I make us of the norm that I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Filling in all the details in this proof may answer your doubts in the last line. Why does $f_n$ converges in $C^0([a,b];X)$? Without the given norm, we can't even say anything about pointwise convergence, let alone uniform convergence. To understand the issue better, it's helpful to write down a detailed proof.